# Can be "JIT compilation using LLVM" Postgres 11 func enabled on AWS RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, jit

How I can turn on/off subj feature on my AWS RDS PG 11 db?

[About PG feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/jit-reason.html)

> PostgreSQL has builtin support to perform JIT compilation using LLVM when PostgreSQL is built with --with-llvm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer in aws docs:

> Support for Just-In-Time (JIT) capability – RDS PostgreSQL 11 instances are created with JIT capability, speeding evaluation of expressions. `To enable this feature, set jit to ON.`

Doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.version111

Comment: Ok, I added link